# creating a dropdown menu when focus

Tags: html, css

can you help me? i want to create a dropdown menu when it focus pure css no jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="pp-nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Furoms</a></li>

                <li tabindex="1" class="pp-dropdown-toggle">
                    <a href="#">Blogs</a>
                    <ul class="pp-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Application</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pp-dropdown-toggle {
  position: relative;
 }

.pp-dropdown-toggle .pp-dropdown {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
}

.pp-dropdown-toggle:focus ul.pp-dropdown {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

this code works in Chrome and ie but in mozilla its not work
can you help me for this problem

Comment: These menus are 10 a dozen my friend. Just search and choose one that's looks good for you from the net. --- here are some --- http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/stunning-free-jquery-dropdown-menus

Comment: Hover or Focus? I did think that li elements cannot be focused in

Comment: You are trying to focus on li but in IE and Mozilla li elements cannot be focused in

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply change your CSS selector to:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fU684/3/)

```
.pp-dropdown-toggle:focus ul.pp-dropdown, .pp-dropdown-toggle a:focus + ul.pp-dropdown {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: hello.. i have another question to you can you modify the code when the menu focus the dropdown will show then if it is focus again the dropdown will hide..

Comment: @RK-boy - you may want to post this as a new question in order to gain more attention from the community

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  You can't actually get the links in the sub-menu that you click on to fire.  If you put a real link href in your submenu links in the fiddle, it won't actually follow to those links when you click on them.  Instead, the menu just disappears.  My guess is that the link you're clicking on grabs focus and that immediately hides the sub-menu and then it doesn't process the `<a>` link you were trying to click on.

Comment: Try clicking on the "blogs" drop-down, then on the "Google" link in that sub-menu as shown in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aovszh0e/).  The link to google.com doesn't actually work.  The sub-menu  disappears and the link you clicked on is not followed.  How would you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/fU684/10/):

```
.pp-dropdown-toggle {
  position: relative;
 }

.pp-dropdown-toggle .pp-dropdown {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
}
/* if you also need hover */
/* it is behind the css3, so you can not to worry about cross browser compatibility  */
.pp-dropdown-toggle:focus > ul.pp-dropdown, .pp-dropdown-toggle:hover > ul.pp-dropdown {
    visibility: visible;
}
/* answer for your question in the comments */
.pp-dropdown-toggle:not(:focus) > ul.pp-dropdown, .pp-dropdown-toggle:not(:hover) > ul.pp-dropdown {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

If it didn't help try to target not to li element but to a link, like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/fU684/11/).